# Typescript: How do I create a mapped type from an union of object with single keys?

Tags: typescript, union, mapped-types

What I want to do is the following:

Say I have a type:

```
type UpdateUnion =
    {foo:number} |
    {bar:string} |
    {baz: {value1: number, value2: string}};
```

Is there a way to construct a mapped type like this?

```
type UpdateFunctions = {
    foo: (value: number) => void,
    bar: (value: string) => void,
    baz: (value: {value1: number, value2:string}) => void
};
```

So far I've tried this:

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type UpdateFunctions = {
    [Key in KeysOfUnion<UpdateUnion>]: (value: UpdateUnion[Key]) => void
}
```

This only seems to work if there is only one possible value in the union, otherwise I get the error: Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'UpdateUnion'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Extract` utility type to extract values from a union that match a certain type.

Using this, you can extract the object with the key you want before trying to select the value of that key.

```js
type UpdateUnion =
  | { foo:number }
  | { bar:string }
  | { baz: { value1: number, value2: string } };

type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

type UpdateFunctions = {
  [Key in KeysOfUnion<UpdateUnion>]: (value: Extract<UpdateUnion, { [K in Key]: unknown }>[Key]) => void
}
```

This produces the type you want.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYEYDsCWB7NUC8AUFFAN5QBmWWAXGgK4C2ARhAE5QC+UAPkaVE0StqAZ2CsMaAOacefMoIBe1fgDdEAGzoQAjCvrM2AGijqtEAEwqxE6Rw4BuAgVCQoAaQggRAeXLpsNAAeABUAPnwoEKgIAA8UNHgRKKgAfigAay8schT9CFU2J1doOCQUADE6NABjYEDkvFI+AG1PEChJDy9ff0wcILLkVH60MIBdFQAKM20VAFF41kQ6wYRhgJwTMjbO3HbJqGqMtCwAd1wOMLavcYBKfAjVLAx4Ag4XcGhgSKHK6rqDQIAHpgcQoAA9VIEIA)

Comment: I have tried something similar to your approach and it seems to work: ```type PickType<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = T extends { [k in K]: any } ? T[K] : never;```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative approach, you can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to get the desired key:

```
type UpdateFunctions<T> = {
  [K in T as keyof K]: (value: K[keyof K]) => void;
};
```

Key remapping allows us to change the key to something else. For instance, in the case, if we want to create a setter function for some property. If we have a property `foo: number` we would need to create `setFoo: (value: number) => void`.
Example without key remapping:

```
type Obj = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  oth: boolean;
};

type CreateSetters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (value: T[K]) => void;
};

// type Result = {
//     foo: (value: string) => void;
//     bar: (value: number) => void;
//     oth: (value: boolean) => void;
// }
type Result = CreateSetters<Obj>;
```

With key remapping:

```
type CreateSetters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as `set${Capitalize<K & string>`]: (value: T[K]) => void;
};

// type Result = {
//     setFoo: (value: string) => void;
//     setBar: (value: number) => void;
//     setOth: (value: boolean) => void;
// }
type Result = CreateSetters<A>;
```

In the latter case, instead of `K` we use `set${Capitalize<K & string>`, which creates a key that starts with `set` and capitalized `K` which is achieved by using the built-in utility type [Capitalize](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype). Note that `K` is `string | number | symbol` and `Capitalize` accepts only `string`, thus we take the intersection of `K` with `string`, which guarantees that it will be a string.

Usage:

```
// type Result = {
//   foo: (value: number) => void;
//   bar: (value: string) => void;
//   baz: (value: {
//       value1: number;
//       value2: string;
//   }) => void;
// }
type Result = UpdateFunctions<UpdateUnion>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYEYDsCWB7NUC8AsAFBRQA+UA3lAGZZYBcUaArgLYBGEATlAL7FSFah0TcmAZ2DcMaAOb9B5KlFEAvJtQBuiADYsIARiatOPANxQd+iACZJ02Qr79zxYqEiwEyCADEWNABjYGw0CQAeABUAPnwqJQBtAGkoWSgoqEQJKABrCBAsGihkgF0mAAprAyZkxPzC4rKASnw4rSwMeDciPh6PcGgAJQgJFl1geLgkFADg0JxI6d90MJjiAHoN0igAPQB+IA)

Comment: `[K in keyof T]: (value: T[K]) => void` works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't. It gives a union. Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYEYDsCWB7NUC8AsAFBRQA+UA3lAGZZYBcUaArgLYBGEATlAL7FSFah0TcmAZ2DcMaAOb9B5KlFEAvJtQBuiADYsIARiatOPANxQd+iACZJ02Qr79zxYqEiwEyCADEWNABjYGw0CQAeABUAPnwqJQBtAGkoWSgAawgQLBooKIBdJgAKawMmKJSCgEp8OK0sDHhiFwgADxQ0eAk0tBoeKAAlKAB+KhTezOzcoaKhqpcTCC0LdyJPaEGICRZdYHi4JBQA4NCcSMPfdDCYtyIgA)

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's strange how typescript generics always require some convoluted syntax as soon as you want anything that's a bit outside of the very simplest things.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what that key remapping is doing? I understand it, but it would make the answer much more useful, especially for less advanced users.

Comment: Aside from that, I much prefer this to my answer.

Comment: @super It's not an issue of generics: it would be the same if you used `UpdateUnion` straight in `UpdateFunctions` instead of generics. It is because of the data structure: the `K in T` iterates over the elements of the union, the `as keyof K` remaps the element to the sole key in the element and uses that as the key. The `K[keyof K]` then uses this sole key of `K` to index into it and get the type of that property.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I've updated the answer with the explanation of key remapping

Comment: I was thinking more of the specific usage here, where you are using it to iterate through a union but then use a key of the union element as the key. The basics of key remapping can be found all over the internet. :)